# Wieso schafft man wie ein "Brunnenputzer"?

Tags: etymology, dialect, proverb, swabian

Im Schwäbischen gibt es die Redewendung *"der schafft wie ein [Brunnenputzer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Brunnenputzer)"* für hart arbeitende Menschen.

> - Er arbeitete sich vom Verkäufer zum Marketing-Direktor hoch. Die ersten 15 Berufsjahre habe er „geschafft wie ein **Brunnenputzer**“.<sup>[Focus](http://www.focus.de/finanzen/news/tid-23920/liqui-moly-boss-ernst-prost-geschafft-wie-ein-brunnenputzer_aid_675446.html)</sup>
> - Der schafft wie ein **Brunnenputzer**, heißt es von besonders fleißigen Menschen. Die Tätigkeit ist harte Arbeit, wissen die Mitarbeiter des Betriebshofes.<sup>[Hohenzollerische Zeitung](http://www.swp.de/hechingen/lokales/hechingen/Wie-ein-Brunnenputzer;art5612,439229)</sup>

Ist etwas zur Herkunft dieser Wendung bekannt? Kennt man den Ausdruck auch außerhalb des schwäbischen Sprachraumes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Brunnenputzen war ein wirklich hartes Stück Arbeit.

Brunnen mussten regelmäßig gereinigt werden, um die Wasserqualität zu gewährleisten. Zunächst wurde die Brunnenröhre von allerlei hinein gefallenem Unrat freigeräumt. Eine schwere Arbeit, zu der oft mehrere kräftige Personen nebst Zugtieren eingesetzt wurden. Dann wurde der Brunnen trockengeschöpft. Hierbei musste man schneller Wasser heraus befördern als neu in den Brunnen einfloss. Der Brunnenputzer bürstete und spülte die Wände und die Sohle so lange, bis das Spülwasser klar blieb. Während dieser Zeit musste ständig weiter geschöpft werden, so dass er seine Arbeit **unter höchstem Zeitdruck und möglichst ohne Pause** verrichtete. Die Verletzungsgefahr war wegen der schnell auf- und abfahrenden Schöpfeimer groß. Je kürzer sein Aufenthalt unten war, desto besser, denn es drohte der Erstickungstod durch Gasansammlung.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt nur wenig Hintergrundwissen zur Redensart *"schaffen wie ein Brunnenputzer"*.

Es scheint aber tatsächlich so zu sein, dass das Säubern (*"putzen"*) der Brunnen eine anstrengende wie hoch angesehene Tätigkeit war:

> *In den Städten und Dörfern wurden zunächst Grundwasserbrunnen in Form von Schachtbrunnen angelegt, aus denen die Bewohner das Wasser mit Eimern oder Krügen heraufholten. Diese Brunnen hatten meist noch keine Einfassung, so dass Staub, Abfälle und hineingefallene Tiere das Brunnenwasser verschmutzten. Später wurden die Brunnen mit einer halbhohen Mauer eingefasst und "**Brunnenputzer**" wurden beauftragt, die öffentlichen und privaten Brunnen von Schlamm und Abfall zu reinigen.* <sup>[K.W. Evers: Wasser als Lebensmittel](http://books.google.de/books?id=PiD8_NTVb2UC&lpg=PA47&ots=J-6R4_oBaF&dq=tier%20brunnenputzer&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q=tier%20brunnenputzer&f=false)</sup>

So kommt auch Rolf-Bernhard Essig in seinen ["Essigessenzen" vom 9.5.2008 im Deutschlandradio](http://www.dradio.de/dkultur/sendungen/essigsessenzen/782972/) zu folgender Aussage:

> *Die Brunnen waren ja extrem wichtig für die Versorgung der dörflichen oder kleinstädtischen Bevölkerung. So gab es den Beruf des Brunnenmeisters, der sich als Leitungskraft um alles frische Wasser und Abwasser kümmerte, für die schwierigen, anstrengenden und schmutzigen Arbeiten aber seine Hilfskräfte hatte, zu denen die Brunnenputzer gehörten. [...] Das alles war eine sehr anstrengende und immer wieder zu verrichtende Arbeit, die deshalb auf alle möglichen Tätigkeiten übertragen wurde, um deren besondere Qualität oder besonderes Ausmaß oder besondere Intensität auszudrücken. Deshalb gibt es außer "schwitzen" auch "**arbeiten**" oder "trinken **wie ein Brunnenputzer**".*